# MySQL query not executing

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$mail=$_REQUEST['email'];
$yname=$_REQUEST['yname'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE uname = '$name' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

    $query=mysql_query("INSERT into noresult (Serial,searchname,yourname,email)
        VALUES ('',$name','$yname','$mail')");
    if ($query){
        header('Location:nullresult.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "Query failure";
    }

}

?>
```

This returns 'Query Failure'. It was working sometime back with table name 'seeker'. Then I dropped it and created a new table 'noresult' as the previous one was a bit messed up. Suddenly the query fails.

**Note:** seeker and noresult have same columns.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.  You can also see http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives and explanation of the danger.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about these. As a beginner my primary goal was to see whether I could implement certain things. Will take care of the issues next time.

Comment: The other big benefit of using prepared statements is that you don't run into the quoting problems that you ran into above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a single quote in your query:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT into noresult (Serial,searchname,yourname,email)
    VALUES ('','$name','$yname','$mail')");
      there----^
```

Comment: I'd double check the casing of `Serial` vs. `serial`, too, if this doesn't solve it for you right away. +1

Comment: From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html): "Column and index names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases." However, table names are case-sensitive on certain platforms, so you may want to check `noresult`.

Comment: There is no issue of casing. I tried with both `serial` and `Serial`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated query-

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT into noresult (Serial,searchname,yourname,email)
        VALUES ('','".$name."','".$yname."','".$mail."')");
```

also check all column name from table noresult.